# Add Post Id to Badges table when applicable

Tags: feature-request, badges, data-explorer

Many badges are awarded for specific posts (Great Answer, Notable Question, Publicist, Investor, etc). In such cases, the list of badges includes the post for which it was awarded. This is public information, as it should be.

However, this information is not present in the Data Explorer *Badges* table. This table has Badge Id and User Id, but no Post Id. ([See this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/208685/publicist-badges) for illustration). I feel this significantly reduces the usefulness of the table. For example, the publicist badge indicates that *some* posts on the site were shared far and wide, but *we do not know which ones*.

I propose adding Post Id column to the table, leaving it Null when not applicable.

Comment: I am surprised I cannot find a duplicate for this.

Comment: Yeah, I was running into this the other day (as my [effective FGITW query times out on Stack Overflow](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202700); if the badges had post ids that query be so much more efficient), but I *assumed* the request would already be made and didn't even look!

Comment: It would be nice to have this information available through the API as well. http://stackapps.com/questions/3153/can-i-determine-the-post-that-caused-a-user-to-earn-a-badge

Comment: Another nice thing to have would be the tag name for Taxonomist. (Which is more-ore-less in the spirit of this feature request.0